# Can't run popen command in office vba script, Run-time error '32815'

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, ms-office

I'm running Word 16.63 (22070801) on Mac OS BigSur.

And I'm trying to invoke popen in VBA scripts (on MacOS):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As Long

Sub AutoOpen()
    a = popen("whoami", "r")
End Sub
```

But it results in runtime error:

[image]

Everything looks fine to me, does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: For Office 2016 the correct API declaration is `Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr`. What Office version do you use?

Comment: Please, look [here](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/31814/mac-apis) for useful hints/explanations about using API in MacOs.

Comment: @FaneDuru Now it's `Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: @FaneDuru Added word version to the question

Comment: @daisy Try replacing ```libc.dylib``` with ```/usr/lib/libc.dylib```

Comment: @CristianBuse Same error, was it a sandbox issue?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen _
        Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String _
                                 , ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function popen _
        Lib "libc.dylib" (ByVal command As String _
                        , ByVal mode As String) As Long
#End If

Sub AutoOpen()
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim a As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim a As Long
#End If
    a = popen("whoami", "r")
    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```